How to manage ORA$_ATSK_AUTOSTS
There are 2 pluggable db's in the same container db running on Oracle 21c SE2 21.0.0.0.0
One pdb runs ORA$_ATSK_AUTOSTS every 15 minutes and it runs for less than a minute, seen from dba_scheduler_job_run_details.
On the other pdb it runs once a day for 30-50 minutes.
I tried disabling it yesterday :
exec DBMS_AUTO_TASK_ADMIN.DISABLE(client_name => 'auto optimizer stats collection', operation => NULL, window_name => NULL);
But it still ran again this morning.
Logs in dba_scheduler_job_log imply that it was run manually, but I can't see how it was triggered ...
dba_scheduler_job_log.ADDITIONAL_INFO = 'REASON="manual slave run"'
My questions are as follows:

How can I find out what is triggering the job?
Why doesn't the disable proc work?
Why is it running outside of the maintnenance windows dba_autotask_schedule ?
Is there a way to configure the sample size so that it runs for a shorter time ?


Support note 2686869.1 suggests the client_name parameter should be 'Auto STS Capture Task', not 'auto optimizer stats collection', so you might try that.
